# a more relible solution to LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: php, mysql

so I want to link two tables with a common column "messageID". so first I insert into table 1 
to get the Auto incremented id, then take that ID with LAST_INSERT_ID function and give that as the id for table 2:

```
$db->("INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES('','$message')");
$db->("INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$message');
```

but here's my concern, there might be two users running this script simultaneously, so in the few milliseconds between the two queries exicuting the `LAST_INSERT_ID` could have changed, so now the two id's are different. Is there any way I can prevent this possibility. I know it is not possible to insert into two tables with one query, which was my first thoughts. Any ideas much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Note that you're **NOT** inserting the last insert id in your second query. you're inserting a **STRING** that happens to say "last_insert_id". You want `... VALUES (last_insert_id(), '$message')` instead. not the lack of quotes and the addition of `()`.

Comment: quite right, I forgot the parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LAST_INSERT_ID is local to the connection session, so it will not conflict with a different user making an insert.

Comment: Connection session not transaction.

Comment: That is a weight of my mind, Thank you for that good news.

Comment: @MikeB, Thanks Mike... I always get lost in the semantics... answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using scope_identity, which would be something like this:

```
$db->("DECLARE @LAST_ID int
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES('','$message')"
SET @LAST_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
);

$arg = ... $myARR['LAST_ID'] ... //however you want to get the LAST_ID from your query to PHP here

$db->("INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(@arg,'$message');
```

or

```
$db->("DECLARE @LAST_ID int
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES('','$message')"
SET @LAST_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(@LAST_ID,'$message')
);
```

LAST_ID would be the value of the Auto incremented id

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is a function in Microsoft SQL Server, not in MySQL.